# Propositional Logic, not sure if I can ask this on here

Tags: logic

I'm stuck with a big proof in my homework. I have to use natural deduction to prove something, and I think if I can prove this somehow then I can finish the full proof. Can anyone help?

P v Q, ¬P : Q

I have to do it from first principles though, I can't use DM's laws.

I can use the following rules:

implication intro, implication elim, conjunction intro, conjunction elim, disjunction intro, disjunction elim, (double) negation elimination, negation introduction (using Reductio Ad Absurdum)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about formal logic, not programming.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ _could be_ the place for this but I'm not sure.

Comment: For your future reference: [StackExchange -> Philosophy -> Logic](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)

Comment: Philosophy SE has taken such questions in the past. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the question might be off-topic, but find the solution [here](http://www.danielclemente.com/logica/dn.en-node39.html) (the used rules are in the right column of the derivation). It's part of [this](http://www.danielclemente.com/logica/dn.en.html) tutorial on natural deduction. You can check for the notation and abbreviations of the rule names there, it uses [Fitch style derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation) rather than e.g. tree notation, but should be easy to read nonetheless.